# setup file doesnt work on other computers because of database included

Tags: c#, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have created a simple windows application with c# and i added simple database to it (mdf).
It works correctly. but when i create a setup for it and install this, other computer can not open this file but it works correctly on my computer. how can i fix this problem?

Can anyone help me pls?
Here are my simple code:

namespace TestOfSimpleDatabase
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Store.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dat = "Insert into [Table](Fname,Lname) Values('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "' )";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(dat, con);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'storeDataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.storeDataSet.Table);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you install SQL and the database for these other machines to connect to - as the connection string is hard coded to look locally on each of their machines.

Comment: No, i didnt install sql for other computers. i want everything include in setup file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not install SQL server Engine on the user machine, you have to
install the SQL Server on the user machine and attach the MDF file to it and run your program.

OR,

Use MS-ACCESS database instead of SQL Server which does not require installation to the engine of it. This is called embedded database and is supposed to be used only for small number of users like 5 users. But this requires a change in the SQL Provider inside your code.

Comment: If OP is actually using a MDF file, then he _certainly_ needs to install a SQL engine in the other computer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. can i attach sql server Engine into setup file?

Comment: what I need is to include everything in a setup file. and after setup this file, it should have work on other computers.

Comment: @arash6657 IMHO, I do not think this is applicable, SQL server engine needs installation and require feedback from the user to continue the process of installation.

Comment: Always when we buy an application forexample, everything included in a setup file.
i want to create a setup file and install it normally. but it doesnt work although i attached the database in my setup file.
Does anyone try it yet? (to create a setup file included database and it works?)

Comment: @arash6657, That is why I propose in my answer to use another database that does not need a separate installation such as Ms-Access.

Comment: @arash6657, There are many other types of databases you can safely include in your setup file, and many much lighter than Access. You might be better off searching for portable databases, such as SQLite.

Comment: Other than that, the only probable ways are setting up central SQL servers, and accessing them through the network.

Comment: Thanks.
Its not possible to create a database with visual studio?
because this wal also didn't work!

Comment: @ arash6657, what is the name of the database? conceptually each database has its own tool to manage.